# Download all test class from org

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration, data-loader

How to download all test class and coverage of each class from org. Long back i did but i forgot How i downloaded. We can get One Excel sheet. Can anyone please help me how to download all test classes?

Comment: Are you just looking for coverage data?

Comment: Yeah. I need a document for that. coverage data, how many line covered and not covered column wise i need. Can you please help me

Comment: You may find [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/04/monitoring-apex-test-code-coverage.html) of interest. See also [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLZAAY).

Comment: The IdeaExhange URL is moved. The idea for the above comment can be found via below URL https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdY6eUAF/developer-console-exportcopy-list-of-overall-code-coverage

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to quick look on coverage by apex class/trigger-

1. You can use developer console: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&type=5
2. You can make a query on object that stores this data using Tooling API:

   select ApexClassorTriggerId, NumLinesCovered,NumLinesUncovered,Coverage from ApexCodeCoverageAggregate

   [image]

**Now, specific to this question,** there are two way to **download** this info:

1. We can download by making a query on 'ApexCodeCoverageAggregate' and parsing result using apex.
2. EASIEST way to download it to by using Chrome plugin [Advance Code Searcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-advanced-code/lnkgcmpjkkkeffambkllliefdpjdklmi). On setup home page, you can download org test classes coverage info with help of this plugin. 
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/04/monitoring-apex-test-code-coverage.html) of interest. See also [this Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdY6eUAF/developer-console-exportcopy-list-of-overall-code-coverage).

One option that should work is to copy the coverage data from the `Developer Console` and paste it into your spreadsheet. Not pretty, but workable if you just need a quick and dirty solution.